# Sublime text not printing script's output

Tags: python, sublimetext

Sublime text not printing python output. I'm getting output for normal `print()` function call, but the one in the `if` statement is not printing anything.

```
year = int(input('enter year you want to check: '))
if year%4 == 0:
    if year%100 ==0:
        if year%400 == 0:
            print('leap year')
        else:
            print('not leap year')
    else:
        print('leap year')

else:
    print('not a leap year')
```

Screenshot showing no output printed:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code as properly formatted text, not an image.

Comment: There is no loop here.  Which print statement, exactly, is not printing?

Comment: sorry not loop but in if statement

Comment: after i enter input and press enter it does not print output

Comment: This code works for me when I copy-paste it. Maybe try running it elsewhere?

Comment: This video might help you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-d27eACbjnk

Comment: it is working fine in other compiler but when i run this sublimetext im getting this problem

Comment: The one in which `if` statement? You need to be more specific. Could it not be printing because the condition is `False`?

Comment: Thanks, now its working after installing sublimeREPL package